# Postgresql functions and operators can take at most one set argument error

Tags: postgresql

I am playing around with PostGIS and I don't understand what's wrong with this request ?

```
WITH ligne AS (SELECT 42 AS id, ST_transform('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.232 48.818, 2.246 48.82)'::geometry, 27572) AS geom)
SELECT ST_locate_along_measure(ST_addmeasure(geom, 0, ST_Length(geom)), generate_series(0, ST_length(geom)::int, 50)) FROM ligne;
```

I get the error : ERROR:  functions and operators can take at most one set argument

This request is working but I don't understand the difference between both :

```
WITH ligne AS (SELECT 42 AS id, ST_transform('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.232 48.818, 2.246 48.82)'::geometry, 27572) AS geom),
ligne3dm AS (SELECT ST_addmeasure(geom, 0, ST_Length(ligne.geom)) as geom FROM ligne),
pas50m AS (SELECT generate_series(0, ST_length(ligne.geom)::int, 50) as pas FROM ligne)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, ST_locate_along_measure(ligne3dm.geom, pas50m.pas) FROM ligne3dm, pas50m;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, generate_series return a generator but ST_Locate_Along_Measure is waiting for an integer.

This will work:

```
WITH ligne AS (SELECT 42 AS id, ST_transform('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.232 48.818, 2.246 48.82)'::geometry, 27572) AS geom),
generator AS (SELECT generate_series(0, ST_Length(ligne.geom)::int, 50) as pas FROM ligne)
SELECT ST_locate_along_measure(ST_addmeasure(ligne.geom, 0, ST_Length(ligne.geom)), generator.pas) FROM ligne, generator;
```